# JOOQ and Oracle REF CURSOR streaming

Tags: java, sql, jooq

JOOQ, by default, wraps REF CURSOR out parameters as `Result<Record>` in generated code.

In some cases - for large reports, it will be better to have stream of Record - `Cursor<Record>` or `Stream<Record>` than fetch all records at once.

Have we any possibility to change generated code for this case or achieve streaming of `Record` for REF CURSOR in JOOQ by other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently (jOOQ 3.12) not possible, I'm afraid. There are some pending feature requests in that area:

- [#4503](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4503) Add `org.jooq.Cursors extends Iterable<Cursor<Record>>`
- [#4472](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4472) Add `Routine.executeLazy()` to allow for fetching `org.jooq.Cursors`

Depending on the database product you're using, you could wrap your `REF CURSOR` returning procedure in a table valued function, though, and fetch the results in an ordinary `SELECT` statement using jOOQ's `ResultQuery.fetchLazy()` method. This would work with both Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Comment: May we use following scenario using JOOQ without wrapping pl/sql table in table function?


Obtain `ConnectionProvider` with `Configuration.connectionProvider()`.



Acquire and release `javax.sql.Connection` with
`ConnectionProvider.acquire()`
`ConnectionProvider.release()`.



Make `CallableStatement` with `javax.sql.Connection`.
Register REF CUSOR out parameter with `OracleTypes.CURSOR` .



Wrap `ResultSet` from out parameter with `Cursor<Record>`
using `DSLContext.fetchLazy`.

Comment: `Cursor<Record>` must be used between `ConnectionProvider.acquire()` and  `ConnectionProvider.release()` calls

Comment: @aelor: I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting here, but then again, Stack Overflow comments are not a good media for more complex discussions. May I invite you to ask your question on the user group (https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user), or on github (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose), instead?